# How to set up payments service on Flutter app

Tags: flutter, paypal, payment

I am building an app which allows charities to sign up and allow people to donate to different charities.
How do i set this up on Flutter where when a user donates the money is transferred to the specified charity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json file inside your app that contains charity destination payment info. use [Paytm Plugin for payment](https://pub.dev/packages/paytm)
then you just have to call json according to action of user To donates the money transferred to the specified charity.

Comment: It is not available in Ireland do you have any other suggestions?